# How to get the app instance within the controller?

Tags: loopbackjs

I started using Loopback4 on a small app I am making.

The app is periodically retrieving data from an external site and the data is stored in a variable in the app object.

Now I'm a bit stuck as I don't know how to get the app instance within the controller. Do I inject it? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the application object using the binding key `CoreBindings.APPLICATION_INSTANCE`.

```js
import {CoreBindings, inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {MyApplication} from '../application';

export class MyController {
  constructor(
    @inject(CoreBindings.APPLICATION_INSTANCE)
    private app: MyApplication,
  ) {}

  // ...
}
```

Documentation: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.core.corebindings.application_instance.html

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.core.corebindings.application_instance.html

Just gonna add the api doc link here. I hope it helps others too. Thanks! @miroslav-bajtoš

Comment: @ProNoob thank you for the link, I added it to my answer to make it even easier to find.